# Reading data from xml file with currency rates (ecb) to calculate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new here and don't know exactly how to start. If I do something wrong (in asking my question), please feel free to tell me.

The Problem that I have is simple for you, I guess. I'm trying to read data from the XML file (the ecb publishes daily): [currency rates](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml)

I do get it done, but probably in the most inefficient way possible. You might get tears in your eyes. :-)

My code is:

```
while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.Name != "")
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < xmlReader.AttributeCount; i++)
                {
                    //Prüfen ob es den Knoten/Element 'Cube' gibt
                    if (xmlReader.Name == "Cube")
                    {
                        //Falls der Knoten/Element nur 1 Attribut enthält, ist dies das Datum
                        if (xmlReader.AttributeCount == 1)
                        {
                            //Datum auslesen
                            xmlReader.MoveToAttribute("time");
                            tempDatum = DateTime.Parse(xmlReader.Value);
                        }
                        //Sind 2 Attribute im aktuellen Knoten/UnterElement, enthält dieser WährungsKürzel und Kurswert
                        if (xmlReader.AttributeCount == 2)
                        {
                            //Währung auslesen
                            xmlReader.MoveToAttribute("currency");
                            tempWaehrung = xmlReader.Value;

                            //Kurs auslesen
                            xmlReader.MoveToAttribute("rate");
                            tempKurs = double.Parse(xmlReader.Value.Replace(".", ",")); // Komma als DecimalSymbol



                            if (tempWaehrung.Equals("AUD")) AUD.Text = tempKurs.ToString();
                            if (tempWaehrung.Equals("BRL")) BRL.Text = tempKurs.ToString();
                            if (tempWaehrung.Equals("BGN")) BGN.Text = tempKurs.ToString();
                            /*and 29 other currencies...*/

                            //ausgelesene Werte zusammen in einer neuen Zeile eintragen
                            //DataRow neueZeile = dtWechselkurs.NewRow();
                            //neueZeile["Datum"] = tempDatum;
                            //neueZeile["Waehrung"] = tempWaehrung;
                            //neueZeile["Kurs"] = tempKurs;

                            //dtWechselkurs.Rows.Add(neueZeile);
                        }

                        xmlReader.MoveToNextAttribute();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /*foreach (DataRow row in dtWechselkurs.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
            {
                //What should I do here?
            }
        }*/
    }
    protected void calculateCurrencies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AUDamount.Text = (double.Parse(euro.Text) * double.Parse(AUD.Text)).ToString("0.00");
        //and 31 other currencies...
    }
```

I have a TextBox where the user puts in the amount and gets the calculated values (via calculateCurrencies_Click).

[Pic for rate and amount of Australian Dollar, it's the same for all the other currencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOqsw.jpg)

I understand that the XMLReader is working. But I need some kind of data structure, probably like the DataTable. But I don't know how to go through it to avoid the if clauses:

if (tempWaehrung.Equals("AUD")) AUD.Text = tempKurs.ToString();

I just want the tempWaehrung to be the name of the variable. And I am parsing from double to string back and forth and use the labels to store the currency rate instead of using the proper data structure (I don't know which one) to do the calculation.

Since my English is pretty bad, I hope you guys understand what I'm trying to do here. There has to be a better way to do it.

Thank you in advance for your help, smart guys.

Greetings
Albrecht

Answer (score 2):

I think, you get the `xml` from `api` like a `string`, then you can use 
[XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netframework-4.8)
and [Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_Parse_System_String_) 
method to parse your xml like a `string`, and use [Linq to xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) 
to get the **currency** and **rate**.

1 - Create a method, that take the `xml` and return a `dictionary` (Currency, Rate)

```
private static Dictionary<string, decimal> GetCurrencyAndRateFromXml(string xml)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    XNamespace xn = "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";

    return doc
        .Descendants(xn + "Cube")
        .Descendants()
        .Descendants()
        .Select(x => new { currency = x.Attribute("currency").Value, rate = x.Attribute("rate").Value })
        .ToDictionary(x => x.currency, 
            value => decimal.TryParse(value.rate, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), out decimal longValue) ? longValue : 0);
}
```

2 - Create a method, that take the string price(**euro.Text**) and Rate

```
private static decimal GetCalculatedPrice(string price, decimal rate)
{
    if (decimal.TryParse(price, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), out decimal newPrice))
        return newPrice * rate;
    return 0;
}
```

3 - Calling methods in `calculateCurrencies_Click`, like :

```
protected void calculateCurrencies_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dictionary<string, decimal> keyValuePairs = GetCurrencyAndRateFromXml(xml);
    // keyValuePairs["AUD"] gives you rate of AUD from dictionary
    AUDamount.Text = GetCalculatedPrice(euro.Text, keyValuePairs["AUD"]).ToString("0.00"); 
    //and 31 other currencies...
}
```

4 - TEST

```
    string xml = @"
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes=""http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"" xmlns=""http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref"">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time=""2020-03-13"">
            <Cube currency=""USD"" rate=""1.1104""/>
            <Cube currency=""JPY"" rate=""119.11""/>
            <Cube currency=""BGN"" rate=""1.9558""/>
            <Cube currency=""CZK"" rate=""26.042""/>
            <Cube currency=""DKK"" rate=""7.4732""/>
            <Cube currency=""GBP"" rate=""0.89070""/>
            <Cube currency=""HUF"" rate=""338.88""/>
            <Cube currency=""PLN"" rate=""4.3570""/>
            <Cube currency=""RON"" rate=""4.8213""/>
            <Cube currency=""SEK"" rate=""10.8453""/>
            <Cube currency=""CHF"" rate=""1.0608""/>
            <Cube currency=""ISK"" rate=""150.00""/>
            <Cube currency=""NOK"" rate=""11.0966""/>
            <Cube currency=""HRK"" rate=""7.5630""/>
            <Cube currency=""RUB"" rate=""80.7385""/>
            <Cube currency=""TRY"" rate=""6.9850""/>
            <Cube currency=""AUD"" rate=""1.7684""/>
            <Cube currency=""BRL"" rate=""5.2042""/>
            <Cube currency=""CAD"" rate=""1.5389""/>
            <Cube currency=""CNY"" rate=""7.7587""/>
            <Cube currency=""HKD"" rate=""8.6255""/>
            <Cube currency=""IDR"" rate=""16400.61""/>
            <Cube currency=""ILS"" rate=""4.0867""/>
            <Cube currency=""INR"" rate=""81.8765""/>
            <Cube currency=""KRW"" rate=""1341.38""/>
            <Cube currency=""MXN"" rate=""23.7835""/>
            <Cube currency=""MYR"" rate=""4.7508""/>
            <Cube currency=""NZD"" rate=""1.8120""/>
            <Cube currency=""PHP"" rate=""56.453""/>
            <Cube currency=""SGD"" rate=""1.5684""/>
            <Cube currency=""THB"" rate=""35.244""/>
            <Cube currency=""ZAR"" rate=""17.9235""/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>";

Dictionary<string, decimal> keyValuePairs = GetCurrencyAndRateFromXml(xml);
string AUDamount = GetCalculatedPrice("100", keyValuePairs["AUD"]).ToString("0.00");
Console.WriteLine(aUDamount);
```

5 - Result

```
176.84
```

**Note** : 
Always use `TryParse` instead `Parse`, because the Parse throw an exception if *string* is not valid *number*.

Namespace for *linq to xml* : `System.Xml.Linq;`

I hope that will help you out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. It works pretty good for me. I'm sorry, that I can't find the button to vote your answer up. Maybe it's one of the previleges?

Comment: [Upvote and accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), try to apply this explanation.maybe can you help to accept and upvote the answer please.I think you have privilege now